# Modify TableLayout columns size in android with java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have designed a table for android app which needs to be dynamic and should populate data from mysql database. The design has been implemented from java code.

### **However, Im facing a problem with a column in that table which does not appear in the screen but still displays the data which is not visible in the screen.**

I want to know how can I fix this problem and avoid table to appear off the screen. 
Since i can't upload the image..the image of how the table is...is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ut3axf9sjgfcge/2014-03-28-17-13-39%20%282%29.jpg?m=)

Answer (score 0):

On your `TableLayout` issue Android APIs section says:

> The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in that column. However, a TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable by calling setColumnShrinkable() or setColumnStretchable(). If marked as shrinkable, the column width can be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space. The total width of the table is defined by its parent container. It is important to remember that a column can be both shrinkable and stretchable. In such a situation, the column will change its size to always use up the available space, but never more. Finally, you can hide a column by calling setColumnCollapsed().

That is why for your purpose use `setColumnShrinkable()` for a column which content comes out of the screen.

For additional details check, please, [documetations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) the TableLayout tutorial below: [Android User Interface Design: Table Layouts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-table-layouts--mobile-4788)

Comment: ghoshak..iv tried to build another table by refering to the websites you gave me..but i still get the problem. The problem is that the row as well as the table gets distorted when a column has big data to display.